# Basic Lighting OpenGl

Tags: c++, opengl

I am trying to add a basic lighting to my OpengGl scene. I modified the fragment and vertex shaders, but I have no idea how to combine in fragment shader "fragmentColour = texture(diffuseTexture, passTexture);" in order the lighting to be applied to the whole scene. I tried to add fColor = vec4(color, 1.0f); but in this case the texture isn't visible anymore. Here is my vertex and fragment shaders:

//vertexShader

```
#version 400

layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertexPosition;
layout(location = 1) in vec3 vertexNormal;
layout(location = 2) in vec2 textcoord;

out vec3 colour;
out vec2 passTexture; 

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;
uniform mat3 normalMatrix;

//lighting
uniform vec3 lightDir;
uniform vec3 lightColor;
uniform vec3 baseColor;

vec3 ambient;
float ambientStrength = 0.2f;
vec3 diffuse;
vec3 specular;
float specularStrength = 0.5f;
float shininess = 32.0f;

void main() {
//compute ambient light
ambient = ambientStrength * lightColor;

//normalize the light's direction
vec3 lightDirN = normalize(lightDir);
//compute eye coordinates for normals (transform normals)
vec3 normalEye = normalize(normalMatrix * vertexNormal);
//compute diffuse light
diffuse = max(dot(normalEye, lightDirN), 0.0f) * lightColor;


//compute the vertex position in eye coordinates
vec4 vertPosEye = view * model * vec4(vertexPosition, 1.0f);
//compute the view (Eye) direction (in eye coordinates, the camera is at the origin)
vec3 viewDir = normalize(- vertPosEye.xyz);
//compute the light's reflection (the reflect function requires a direction pointing towards the vertex, not away
//from it)
vec3 reflectDir = normalize(reflect(-lightDir, normalEye));
//compute specular light
float specCoeff = pow(max(dot(viewDir, reflectDir), 0.0f), shininess);
specular = specularStrength * specCoeff * lightColor;


//compute final vertex color
colour = min((ambient + diffuse) * baseColor + specular, 1.0f);


passTexture = textcoord; 
    gl_Position = projection * view * model * vec4(vertexPosition, 1.0);
}
```

//fragmentShader

```
#version 400

in vec3 colour;
in vec2 passTexture; 
out vec4 fColor;

out vec4 fragmentColour;
uniform sampler2D diffuseTexture; 
void main() {

    fragmentColour = texture(diffuseTexture, passTexture); 
fColor = vec4(color, 1.0f);


}
```

Comment: Most of the things you did in the vertex shader you shall do in the fragment shader instead. Basically your `baseColor` shall be the value you sample from the `diffuseTexture`.

Comment: not relevant, but it is much better the do (model * view * projection) on the CPU and then pass it as one matrix than  doing... (model * view * projection) for every single vertex of every mesh

Comment: I tried to use diffuseTexture in vertexShader as baseColor, but it isn't working. Although, if a use just "fragmentColour = texture(diffuseTexture, passTexture); " my scene has its previous color and, if I use just "Color = vec4(color, 1.0f);" the texture isn't visible, but the lighting is being applied...

Comment: As @ybungalobill said, you've done things in the vertex shader that need to go to the fragment shader. If you want to keep it this way send `diffuse, ambient,specular` from the vertex shader to the fragment shader, and then in the fragment shader use the texture color as the `baseColor` variable in your colour calculation. Then just output the colour from the fragment shader